# Priority queue of multiple classes C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue

```
class Event{
public:
      enum EventType { A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4};

      Event(EvtType type = A_1, double etime = 0.0)
           : _type(type)
           , _etime(etime)
      {}

      EventType get_Type() const { return _type; };
      double get_Time() const { return _etime; }

protected:
      EventType _type;
      double _etime;
};

struct EventLess{

    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const
        {
         return (lhs.get_Time() > rhs.get_Time());
        }
};
```

I can create min priority queue as below

```
 priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, EventLess> q;
```

However, if I have another class like:

```
class Event1
{
public:
     enum EventType { disruption_1, disruption_2};

     Event(EvtType type = disruption_1, double htime = 0.0, double duration)
          : _type(type)
          , _htime(htime)
          , _duration(duration)

     {}

     EventType get_Type() const { return _type; };
     double get_Time() const { return _htime; }
     double get_Duration() const { return _duration; }

 protected:
     EventType _type;
     double _etime;
     double _duration;
 };
```

and I want to create the min priority queue of these two classes (Time comparing). 
Please anyone demonstrate me how to solve this will be thankful.

---

After receiving suggestion, I have improved a code by using inheritance as presented.

```
    #include <queue>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class IEvent{
    public:
        IEvent(double time_e): Etime(time_e) {}
        virtual double get_Time() const {return Etime;}
    protected:
        double Etime;

    };

    class Event1:public IEvent{
    public:
    enum EType1 { A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4};

    Event1(EType1 type1, double time_e, int _speed)
    : _type1(type1)
    , IEvent(time_e)
    , speed(_speed)
    {}

    virtual EType1 get_Type() const { return _type1; };
    virtual double get_Time() const { return Etime; }
    int get_speed() const {return speed;}

    private:
        EType1 _type1;
        int speed;
    };


    class Event2:public IEvent{
    public:
    enum EType2 { disruption_1, disruption_2};

    Event2(EType2 type2, double time_e, double duration)
    : _type2(type2)
    , IEvent(time_e)
    , _duration(duration)
    {}

    virtual EType2 get_Type() const { return _type2; };
    virtual double get_Time() const { return Etime; }
    double get_duration() const { return _duration; }

    private:
       EType2 _type2;
      double _duration;

    };

    struct IEventLess{

          bool operator()(const IEvent& lhs, const IEvent& rhs) const
          {
           return (lhs.get_Time() > rhs.get_Time());
          }
    };

    int main(){
          priority_queue<IEvent, vector<IEvent>, IEventLess> q;

          q.push(Event1(Event1::A_1, 15.0, 10));
          q.push(Event2(Event2::disruption_1, 5.0, 5.0));

          IEvent *evt;
          evt = new q.top();

          cout <<  evt.get_Type() << evt.get_Time() << endl;
```

}

Nevertheless, I still have some problem in calling other function in derived class, and a little bit confusing when calling top() function as show in main function.

Please anyone help me solve it out.

Thank you.

Comment: One way could be inheritance from a common base and `operator<`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boost::variant` removes the need for a common base class or inheritance:

```
#include <queue>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class Event{
public:
    enum EventType { A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4};

    Event(EventType type = A_1, double etime = 0.0)
    : _type(type)
    , _etime(etime)
    {}

    EventType get_Type() const { return _type; };
    double get_Time() const { return _etime; }

protected:
    EventType _type;
    double _etime;
};

inline double get_time(const Event& e) {
    return e.get_Time();
}

class Event1
{
public:
    enum EventType { disruption_1, disruption_2};

    Event1(EventType type = disruption_1, double htime = 0.0, double duration = 0)
    : _type(type)
    , _etime(htime)
    , _duration(duration)
    {}

    EventType get_Type() const { return _type; };
    double get_Time() const { return _etime; }
    double get_Duration() const { return _duration; }

protected:
    EventType _type;
    double _etime;
    double _duration;
};

inline double get_time(const Event1& e) {
    return e.get_Time();
}


// name predicates properly
struct EventGreater{

    template<class L, class R>
    bool operator()(const L& lhs, const R& rhs) const
    {
        return get_time(lhs) > get_time(rhs);
    }
};

template<class...Ts>
double get_time(const boost::variant<Ts...>& var)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor([](auto& x) { return get_time(x); }, var);
}

struct event_handler : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    void operator()(const Event& e) const
    {
        // handle an Event in here
    }

    void operator()(const Event1& e) const
    {
        // handle an Event1 in here
    }

};

int main()
{
    using EventVariant = boost::variant<Event, Event1>;
    // we all know that a priority queue inverts the predicate
    std::priority_queue<EventVariant, std::vector<EventVariant>, EventGreater> q;


    q.push(Event());
    q.push(Event1());

    //
    // remove an item and action it
    auto ev = std::move(q.top());
    q.pop();

    boost::apply_visitor(event_handler(), ev);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use boost. and I have several questions. Do i need to include #include <boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp>? and when I tried to build i got error massage showing that " no matching function for call to std::priority queue<boost::variant<Event, Event1>..... Could you please suggest me how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: @Rocky depending on your version of boost and/or c++ you may not have lambda support. You may need to build a small functor derived from boost::static_visitor. There are examples in the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works. However, Can you demonstrate me how to top the front element out of the queue in this case? Cheers

Comment: @You mean take?

Comment: @Rocky updated to include popping events from the top of the priority queue and actioning them with a static visitor. priority queues only have 'push', 'pop' and 'top'.  you can't take remove an event out of order (unless you derive from the priority queue and do some trickery with the `c` member.

Comment: Yes, Could you please show me an example of how to use top() function in this case.

Comment: @Rocky it's in the code above - refresh the page and check the main() function again :)

Comment: Thank you very much. From this, "ev" represents the class that is the top of the queue, is not it? or i need to do something else to create an object from the top event in order to use the method inside the class.

Comment: @Rocky ev is the result of moving the object from the top of the queue. the static visitor event_handler is what will call methods in Event1 or Event, depending on the actual event type.

Comment: Ok, I see it now ;).  I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have both `Event` and `Event1` inherit from a common base.

```
class IEvent
{
public:
  virtual double get_Time() = 0;
};

class Event : public IEvent
{
public:
  virtual double get_Time() {...}
}

class Event1 : public IEvent
{
public:
  virtual double get_Time() {...}
}
```

You can then store the base pointers in the queue, and cast to the concrete child when needed.

`std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<IEvent>, std::vector<IEvent>, IEventLess> q;`

```
auto Time = q.front()->get_Time();
```

Comment: if you're going to modify the classes to do inheritance, at least make get_Time defer to a common virtual impl and remove the dynamic casts!

Comment: Can you add the appropriate compare for this?

Comment: @RichardHodges Updated, but with the different `EventType` enumerations they would need to `dynamic_cast` anyway. Although the two enumerations could probably be combined into one in the base as well.

Comment: Because the interfaces of the two classes are dissimilar, I don't think this problem is a candidate for inheritance. One is not a kind-of the other, nor are they a kind-of common type. I think the variant/static visitor approach is more appropriate because it allows relationship to be defined between the two (or more) types via external free functions - At least that's my view given the limited information available in the OP's question. The reality could be different...

Comment: Really good odds you can make `etime` a protected member in the base class and get rid of the virtual methods.

Comment: @RichardHodges Agreed, but not everyone wants to / can use boost. I guess rolling your own EventWrapper variant type is a possibility.

Comment: @Ics, Could  you please clarify you solution a bit more?

Comment: @Rocky My suggestion is just standard inheritance. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/508/classes-structures/1669/inheritance#t=201609122121174318282) is the documentation on it. Basically both events inherit from a common base. So you can declare your array of that common base and have derived instances of either event placed into it.

Comment: I have upgrade my code, but still have some problem. Please anyone help. Thanks